# Saving into Azure root folder when using Azure web deploy

Tags: c#, reactjs, image, azure, asp.net-core

I have a React.Js and .NetCore web app deployed on Azure Web apps where I have chosen Linux as its operating system. I have code that saves an image into the wwwroot (root folder):

[image: save image]

In development, I am able to save and retrieve the image. But once deployed on Azure it does not work. I have chosen the free tier where it says there is 1 GB disk storage. Is there a way to save into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just follow [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#directory-browsing) to let your .NetCore web app to serve static image files.

In my case,my images are saved under path `wwwroot/images` just as this doc indicated. And this is the result below:
[image]

Access this img:
[image]

Create folders dynamically:
I created 2 folders with name: `someuserid` and `abcd`, just as below:
[image]

images also could be accessed by this way:
[image]

You can also try it by this link:
https://stanlinuxtest.azurewebsites.net/images/someuserid/azure-1.png

Comment: Thanks for the solution, just wondering if this will work when needing to create dynamic folders? In my app the scenario is that there is many users with different userIds that will create their own folders dynamically when they register within the web app so the path maybe like this "wwwroot/myImages/UserId/image.jpg".

Comment: Hi @Cgracs , Welcome,glad to know its helpful. Yes , it also works for scenario that creating folders dynamically, I have updated my answer. Pls mark it if it solves your issue :)